# DNS does not work in docker. Docker can reach DNS provider and has correct IP. Host works

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, docker

I have Docker installed on Ubuntu Server 22.04 (via apt not snap). Everything was working until I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. Now, DNS does not work inside docker.

```shell
$ sudo docker run busybox nslookup google.com
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.0.78

*** Can't find google.com: No answer
```

as you can see, docker is attempting to use 1.1.1.1 to resolve the domain but cannot reach it. If we do the same thing on the host

```shell
$ nslookup google.com
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.0.78
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4025:815::200e
```

everything works as expected.

Docker can for sure reach the DNS server because we can ping it

```
$ sudo docker run busybox ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=0 ttl=56 time=13.370 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=1 ttl=56 time=15.364 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=2 ttl=56 time=11.075 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=3 ttl=56 time=10.229 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=4 ttl=56 time=11.113 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: seq=5 ttl=56 time=17.715 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 10.229/13.144/17.715 ms
```

resolv.conf is pretty typical

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 172.17.0.1
```